# Splitting settings.py in prod and dev causing a ModuleNotFoundError, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am new to django and trying to deploy my app. I would like to split my *settings* in two (*dev* and *prod*).

When I did `python manage.py runserver` with just one `settings.py` file, it worked perfectly.

I have now the following folder structure:

- apps
- core

  - pycache
  - settings

    - pycache
    - init.py
    - base.py
    - dev.py
    - prod.py
  - init.py
  - asgi.py
  - urls.py
  - utils.py
  - wsgi.py
- media
- etc.

**base.py**

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "apps"))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "my_secret_key"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "account.apps.AccountConfig",
    "address.apps.AddressConfig",
    "basket.apps.BasketConfig",
    "contact.apps.ContactConfig",
    "discount.apps.DiscountConfig",
    "home_page.apps.HomePageConfig",
    "la_marque.apps.LaMarqueConfig",
    "orders.apps.OrdersConfig",
    "payment.apps.PaymentConfig",
    "shipping.apps.ShippingConfig",
    "store.apps.StoreConfig",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django_extensions",
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "core.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "basket.context_processors.basket",
            ],
        },
    },
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = "account.Account"

WSGI_APPLICATION = "core.wsgi.application"

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "monoi_django_test_db.sqlite3",
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Paris"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

When I run `python manage.py runserver --settings=core.settings.dev`, I have the following error:

```
(monoi_virtualenv) C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi>python manage.py runserver --settings=core.settings.dev
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\alexis.lerendu-perne\Documents\monoi_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 212, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'
```

I guess this error has something to do with `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in *base.py* ... Is that correct ? How can I fix this problem ?

**dev.py**

```py
from .base import *
```

**prod.py**

```py
from .base import *
DEBUG = False
```

### EDIT

If I comment the first line of `INSTALLED_APPS`, `account.apps.AccountConfig`, then, I have the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'address'`


If I change `account.apps.AccountConfig` by `account` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, it doesn't change anything. I still have: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'`

**apps/account/apps.py**

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "account"
```

Comment: It seems that Python can't find your apps defined in the INSTALLED_APPS. Is "account" a package that can be imported? Django is trying to do "import account.apps.AccountConfig" via the importlib.import_module function.

Comment: Does it work with `apps.account.apps.AccountConfig`

Comment: To make the server run, I have to modify:
`INSTALLED_APPS = [foo.apps.FooConfig]` with `INSTALLED_APPS = [apps.foo.apps.FooConfig]`

Comment: To make the server run, I have to modify:
`INSTALLED_APPS = [foo.apps.FooConfig]` by `INSTALLED_APPS = [apps.foo.apps.FooConfig]`
ALso, I have to modify all the imports :
`from foo.models import Bar` -> `from apps.foo.models import Bar`
And in *core.urls.py*, I have to change `urlpatterns` like this:
`urlpatterns = path("foo/", include("foo.urls", namespace="foo")` by `urlpatterns = path("foo/", include("apps.foo.urls", namespace="foo")`
It seems that I also need to change the path of the templates, and so on ...
This does not seem to be an elegant solution to solve this issue ...

Answer (score 0):

Try moving default django apps at the top in INSTALLED_APPS like this.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django_extensions",
    .... #Your Apps Here
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does work. I still have this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'` when I run `python manage.py runserver --settings=core.settings.dev`.

Answer (score -1):

In your python environment you have to install pandas library.

You can install split-settings python with following command:

> pip install split-settings

After the installation of split-settings python library, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'split-settings' error will be solved.